# KdenLive Missing MLT module: sdl or rtaudio required for audio output

Tags: 18.04, kdenlive

I just installed kdenlive on ubuntu 18.04 but kdenlive is not starting and every time I try to open a warning message shows up.

[image]

I am new to Ubuntu and don't know what to do. I tried reinstalling the Kdenlive but didn't work. As you can see the version is 19.08.1, I installed it from the Ubuntu snap store. The same version works if installed from other sources.

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same problem using the snap version. Try to use the (older) apt version.

```
sudo apt install kdenlive
```

and make sure you execute